# Does a normal Ultra-Sonic sensor (HC SR04) sense through a Football Net like obstacle?

Tags: sensors, drone

I am planning to to use ultrasonic sensors mounted on a drone for obstacle avoidance. I am not sure if the sensors would be capable of detecting a Net Like obstacle in its path.

Comment: Most likely it will not sense the net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always a chance of picking up the net for a split second, but most likely, you will never accurately detect the net with this type of sensor. There is too little to detect.